# Robot Framework - TypeError: string indices must be integers When Parsing Json

Tags: json, testing, robotframework

I am trying to parse an array of json, But I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Json:

```
{
    'locationId': 'location1',
    'name': 'Name',
    'type': 'Ward',
    'patientId': None,
    'children': [{
        'locationId': 'location2',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': [{
            'locationId': 'location3',
            'name': 'Name',
            'type': 'HospitalGroup',
            'patientId': None,
            'children': None
        }]
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location4',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Hospital',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location5',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location6',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location27',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }]
}
```

I am trying to the get all the locationId values and store the values one by one inside a list.

Here is what I am doing

```
    @{locationIds}=  create list
    :FOR  ${item}  IN   @{Location_Json}
    \  ${locationId}=  set variable  ${item['locationId']}
    \  log  ${locationId}
    \  append to list  ${locationIds}  '${locationId}'
```

I have also tried this

```
    @{locationIds}=  create list
    :FOR  ${item}  IN   @{Location_Json}
    \  ${locationId}=  set variable  ${item['children'][0]['locationId']}
    \  log  ${locationId}
    \  append to list  ${locationIds}  '${locationId}'
```

But I am getting the same error.

The test is failing on this line `${locationId}=  set variable  ${item['locationId']}`

Any help would be apprectiated.

Comment: Can you check with a `Log Many` if your in-memory structure is indeed what you expect it is. It sounds to me that there is a list that you're trying to access using a string.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I have changed the `${item['locationId']}` to `${item["locationId"]}` and now i am able to find only the first location value

Comment: The format is `Log Many     ${Location_Json_List}` Note the `$`

Comment: @A.Kootstra It is indeed the same structure as above json

Comment: Apply the `Log Many` to the children and just loop through them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content of the var `${Location_Json}` is indeed the json sample you've put above, that would explain the exception "string indices must be integers".

The json you are working with is a dictionary (not a list); thus, in this loop:

```
:FOR  ${item}  IN   @{Location_Json}
```

, the value of `${item}` is going to be the keys in the in the dictionary - e.g. `locationId`, `name`, etc of the top-level dictionary.

If you are interested in the "locationId" of the "children" subdict, that will do it - iteration over the "children" items:

:FOR  ${item}  IN   @{Location_Json['children']}

On each iteration the `${item}` is going to be one of the sub-dicts in "children", and you can get its "locationId"

```
\    ${locationId}=  set variable  ${item['locationId']}
```

---

Not related to your issue, put please do not do that:

```
append to list  ${locationIds}  '${locationId}'
```

Do not put the value of `${locationId}` inside the single quotes - what will happen is those quotes will now be a part of the list member.
Say, the value of `${locationId}` is

```
location5
```

with those quotes surrounding it, it will end up as

```
'location5'
```

I don't think that's your goal; with these extra quotes, this will fail:

```
Should Be Equal As Strings    location5      ${locationIds[3]}   # because locationIds[3] will have the extra quotes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that helped me solve my problem, also nice spot with the `'${locationId}'` thanks

Comment: I am able to get all the values one level down but i cannot get the `location3` value

Comment: Sounds like you need a general solution for "get all values of the key X in all sub-dictionaries that might be present in a list/dictionary", where X is "locationId" for you. Imagine the node that had `location3` as value had something in the `children` key - you would then  want to get the value `location3.1` out from it too, I guess.That's a different problem from the one you've put in this question.

Comment: That's okay i think i will create a Custom Keyword for that, thanks