# Travers through a nested json object and store values- Python

Tags: python, json, nested, traversal

This is a follow up on this question. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53392257/robot-framework-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-when-parsing-json/53399657?noredirect=1#comment93693725_53399657)

Also this question is similar but does not solve my problem [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34818782/iterate-through-nested-json-object-and-get-values-with-python)

I am trying to parse a nested json to get Check how many children a specific location has, I am trying to check if `"children:" = None` and increment counter to check how many levels down i need to go in order to get the lowest child, or 
A more efficient solution would be:

I need to get all the child values into a list and keep going until `"children:" = None`.

The Json object can increase in the amount of children so we can have multiple level of children, Which can get messy if I want to nest the list and get the values, How could I do it dynamically?

```
{
    'locationId': 'location1',
    'name': 'Name',
    'type': 'Ward',
    'patientId': None,
    'children': [{
        'locationId': 'Child_location2',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': [{
            'locationId': 'Child_Child_location3',
            'name': 'Name',
            'type': 'HospitalGroup',
            'patientId': None,
            'children': None
        }]
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location4',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Hospital',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location5',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location6',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }, {
        'locationId': 'location27',
        'name': 'Name',
        'type': 'Bed',
        'patientId': None,
        'children': None
    }]
}
```

I tried to do something like this

```
import requests
def Get_Child(URL, Name):
        headers = {
            'accept': 'text/plain',
        }

        response = requests.get(
            URL + Name,
            headers=headers)
        json_data = response.json()
        print (json_data)
        list = []
        for locationId in json_data['locationId']:
            list.append(locationId)
            for children in locationId['children']:
                list.append(children)
```

but that give me the following error,

> ```
> for children in locationId['locationId']: TypeError: string indices must be integers
> ```

Comment: Your starting point should probably be using the parsed JSON, not the raw body.

Comment: you could use a recursive function

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my question. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Your question is no longer internally consistent - access to `json` would be a `NameError`, and I doubt you'd see the same error as before if you fixed that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes you are correct I am getting a diffrent error i Updated my question

Comment: So did you read that error message? What is it telling you? Are you sure you're accessing the object you think you are?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have corrected the error i had a typo sorry about that

Comment: I'd suggest you continue with the same process until you get to an error message that *doesn't* tell you what the problem is and/or you've got a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution fro my problem,

The following code will get all the children and append them to a list

```
class Children():
  def Get_All_Children(self,json_input, lookup_key):
      if isinstance(json_input, dict):
          for k, v in json_input.items():
              if k == lookup_key:
                  yield v
              else:
                  yield from self.Get_All_Children(v, lookup_key)
      elif isinstance(json_input, list):
          for item in json_input:
              yield from self.Get_All_Children(item, lookup_key)


for locations in self.Get_All_Children(self.json_data, 'locationId'):
    self.mylist.append(locations)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows append, but you ask for a count. Here is a recursive way to get the number of children in this JSON if I am understanding you correctly:

```
def get_children(body, c=1):
    if not body.get('children'):
        c += 1
    elif isinstance(body.get('children'), list):
            c += 1
            for subchild in body.get('children'):
                c += 1
                get_children(subchild, c)
    return c

counts = get_children(your_json_blob)
print(counts)
>>> 7
```

Edit: I purposely did not use `if/else` because I don't know if you can have subchildren that are `dict` rather than `list` which would mean you would need extra conditions, but that's up to you if that ends up being the case.